# DocuSign envelopes being returned from API but not on Dashboard under demo.docusign.net

Tags: docusignapi

If this is just behavior from being on the demo site that is fine but this is throwing me off.  Basically I have envelopes being returned that are under no folders via API and the browser Dashboard.  Not sure what else to say or give you other than an example.

Example:
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/644026/envelopes?from_date=4%2F23%2F2014&status=Completed

Why am I getting back envelopeId 69b32b35-8b0e-4a72-993b-d219338eeef2?  I cannot find it in the GUI of any user.  Also, using the API listing all of the folders for each user and then checking the envelopes within those folders.  When I try to view the document using the API it says it has been removed.

Again, if this is just a behavior on the demo site that is fine but I want to get this worked out before we go live if this will be happening on the live site as well.  I could be missing something and it could be the behavior you expect. If so, how do I exclude these random envelopes that are not in the GUI.  I am sure it existed at one point but has been voided/deleted.  I am taking into account checking the deleted folder.

Any more information you need let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the **Demo** environment, at any given point in time when an Envelope is accessible via the API, it should be viewable via the DocuSign web console ***at that same point in time***.

That being said -- envelope data in the **Demo** environment is automatically purged from the system every so often (once an Envelope becomes 1 month old? ...or perhaps sooner, if the Envelope is in the "Deleted" folder???) -- so it might be possible that an (old) Envelope exists in **Demo** when your API request is submitted (so it's ID is contained in the API response), but by the time you go check the web console for the Envelope, or subsequently run additional API requests in an attempt to track down the Envelope, it no longer exists because it's been purged from the system per DocuSign's **Demo** data retention policy.

[Envelopes in the **Production** environment are retained indefinitely (unless you specify otherwise by setting a specific retention policy) -- so if your experiences in Demo are being caused by the Envelopes being automatically purged, you shouldn't run into that issue in **Production**.]

Comment: Okay. I thought that may be the case but wasn't sure.  Thanks for the quick response.